# Docx4j - Docx to PDF convertion; you must invoke FORendererApacheFOP.getFOUserAgent error

Tags: java, docx4j

We want to convert docx to pdf using **docx4j-JAXB-MOXy 8.3.9** and **docx4j-export-fo 8.3.9**, but we are hitting the following error;

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:109)
at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:597)
at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:612)

Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: You must invoke FORendererApacheFOP.getFOUserAgent
at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.renderers.FORendererApacheFOP.render(FORendererApacheFOP.java:124)
at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:168)
at org.docx4j.convert.out.fo.AbstractFOExporter.postprocess(AbstractFOExporter.java:47)
at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:82)
... 76 more
```

Our maven dependencies are as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-MOXy</artifactId>
  <version>8.3.9</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.6</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>docx4j-export-fo</artifactId>
  <version>8.3.9</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

From your deps you are using MOXy, not JAXB-ReferenceImpl.  Not that this should matter.

Looks like you are calling Docx4J.toPDF

This should be fixed at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_8_3_9/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/FopReflective.java

I guess your problem will go away if you remove the old:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.6</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

See also [Docx4j - Docx to Image convertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595802/docx4j-docx-to-image-convertion)

Comment: Thanks for MOXy correction. And, yes I am calling Docx4J.toPDF. I tried docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext: 6.0.0 but I get the following error > Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.docx4j:docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext:jar:6.0.0

Comment: I have changed docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext to version 6.0.0, I still get the same error.   I also tried Docx4J.toFO but I am now getting the following error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.docx4j.convert.out.FOSettings.setOpcPackage(Lorg/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage;)

Comment: You want https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-JAXB-MOXy/8.3.9/jar (as you have).  That and docx4j-export-fo are all you need explicitly. Get rid of docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext entirely!